# Roblox: how to place a player in a specific position

Tags: lua, roblox

I'm a newbie developer of roblox.

I'm trying to place a player in a specific position on first load in this way:

In StarterPlayer > StarterPlayerScripts I added a LocalScript with the following code:

```
local cf = CFrame.new(500, 5, 50)
local Char = game.Players.LocalPlayer
Char.HumanoidRootPart.CFrame = cf
```

When I click play, nothing happen onload.
What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@ItsJustFunboy is half correct, you do need to use the `Model:MoveTo` function, but you might have some other issues as well : timing and LocalScripts.

Timing-wise, you have this code in [StarterPlayerScripts](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/class/StarterPlayerScripts). These LocalScripts execute when the Player joins the game, not when their character model appears. So it's possible that their character doesn't even exist at the time you're telling it to move. If you want to guarantee that the character model exists at the time you run this code, it needs to be in [StarterCharacterScripts](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/class/StarterCharacterScripts).

As for the problem with LocalScripts, they make changes to the world only on your client. Meaning that if you move your character in a LocalScript, then all the other players will still see your character model where it was, not where you moved it. So unless this is intentional, if you want everyone to see this change, you need to move the character model in a server-side Script.

So in a Script in the Workspace or in ServerScriptService, try this :

```lua
-- wait for a player to join the game
game.Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(function(player)
    -- wait for their character to load into the game
    player.CharacterAdded:Connect(function(character)
        -- yield the thread for but a moment so that the character can finish loading
        wait()

        -- move their character
        local targetPosition = Vector3.new(500, 5, 50)
        character:MoveTo(targetPosition)
    end)
end)
```

Comment: Hmmm, after some testing, it appears that moving the Character in a LocalScript does not follow the same replication rules as other objects, and other players _can_ see the location change of your character.  Simply using `game.Players.LocalPlayer.Character:MoveTo(Vector3.new(500, 5, 50))` is enough to move the character model when the LocalScript is in StarterCharacterScripts.

Answer (score 0):

use the MoveTo() function:

```
local plr = game.Players.LocalPlayer
plr.Character:MoveTo(CFrame.new(500, 5, 50))
```

Comment: The [Model:MoveTo](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/function/Model/MoveTo) function takes a Vector3, not a CFrame.